# Пагинация в вордпрес работает в обратном порядке

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

Вот код

```
                <? if( have_posts() ) {
                    ?><div><?
                        while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                            the_content();
                            $categoryPostId = get_the_ID();
                            the_field('author_date');
                        endwhile;
                        echo  "<ul class='pagination'><li>".get_previous_post_link('%link', '%title', true) ."</li><li>".get_next_post_link('%link', '%title', true)."</li></ul>";
                        wp_reset_postdata();
                        wp_reset_query();
                        ?></div><?
                    }
                ?>
```

Пагинация отображается в обратном порядке.
Как решить этот вопрос?

Comment: Тут скорее всего проблема в стилях будет

Comment: Таки решилось стилями